# AddSortField in nest 2 upgrade

Tags: nest

I used to use the add-sort-field=true as an attribute to a property, but with the new nest I can't find the equivalent. Where is it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it has been accidently removed from NEST 2.x. I couldn't find any trace why. Feel free to ask this question if you think it was useful in your case. [Link to the NEST github](http://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net).

As far I as I understand, property was creating `fieldname.sort` field which was `not_analyzed`.

For time being you can handle this by explicit creating field. Unfortunately you won't be able to do this with attribute-based mapping, but you can successfully mix two techniques.

```
var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(indexName, descriptor => descriptor
    .Mappings(map => map
        .Map<Document>(m => m
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(ps => ps
                .String(s => s
                    .Name(n => n.Country)
                    .Fields(f => f
                        .String(ss => ss.Name(n => n.Country.Suffix("sort")).NotAnalyzed()))))
        )));


public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    [String(Name = "c")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it helps you.