# Nest Client alternative for AddSortField in 2.x

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Currently, we use NEST client for all indexing operations where the "AddSortField" was used to sort the analyzed field (along with a sort analyzer). Looks like this option is not available anymore in 2.X. Are there any alternatives for this? Or any recommendations on sorting analyzed fields in 2.X would be much appreciated.

Note: Current NEST and Elasticsearch version being used is 1.X

Thanks,

Pavan

Comment: I hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425486/addsortfield-in-nest-2-upgrade/36426602#36426602) answer will shed some light on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddSortField` in NEST 1.x is just a convenience method for mapping a property as a [`multi_field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/_multi_fields.html) with a `sort` sub-field to be used when sorting; for `string` fields where no `SortAnalyzer` is specified, this field is [`not_analyzed`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/string.html#string).

To achieve the same in NEST 2.x, you can [use fluent mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/auto-map.html#auto-mapping-with-overrides) to map a property as a `multi_field`, adding a `sort` sub-field

```
var descriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor("myindex")
    .Mappings(ms => ms
        .Map<Company>(m => m
            .Properties(ps => ps
                .String(s => s
                    .Name(n => n.Name)
                    // map as multi_field
                    .Fields(fs => fs
                        .String(ss => ss
                            .Name("sort")
                            .Index("sortAnalyzer")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

When [sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/sort-usage.html), you would then sort on `name.sort`

```
var response = client.Search<Company>(s => s
    .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
    .Sort(ss => ss
        .Ascending(p => p.Name.Suffix("sort"))
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: No worries. If it answers your question, please vote and accept answer